# spawning tag - merge request

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-merging

Can we merge [spawning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spawning) into [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)?

The spawning tag has previously been used to discuss spawn locations in a variety of games, but the bulk of these games were Minecraft. I have retagged questions from the other games leaving the remaining questions using this tag as all Minecraft questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DO NOT USE - Removed as part of "The great Arqade clean-up of 2012" - See link in Tag Wiki for more information

Found this in the tag wiki. Might as well blow it to pieces, no? No synonym made, naturally, so this just knocked it into the sky to never be seen again. Until it is remade, anyway.

```
updating post history, 9 rows affected
updating posts, 8 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [minecraft] and [spawning] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```